# How to decode the byte into string in python3

Tags: python-3.x, decode

After receiving the bytes from Server, it needs to convert into string. When I try below code, not works per expected.

```
a
Out[140]: b'NC\x00\x00\x00'

a.decode()
Out[141]: 'NC\x00\x00\x00'

a.decode('ascii')
Out[142]: 'NC\x00\x00\x00'

a.decode('ascii').strip()
Out[143]: 'NC\x00\x00\x00'

a.decode('utf-8').strip()
Out[147]: 'NC\x00\x00\x00'

# I need the Output as 'NC'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an encoding issue, as the trailing bytes are all NUL bytes. Looks like your server is padding with Null bytes. To remove them just use

```
a.strip(b'\x00')
```